# Compare Properties from Array to Single Property in Document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongoDB `orders` collection, the documents of which look as follows:

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59537df80ab10c0001ba8767"),
    "shipments" : {
        "products" : [
            {
                "orderDetails" : {
                    "id" : ObjectId("59537df80ab10c0001ba8767")
                }
            },
            {
                "orderDetails" : {
                    "id" : ObjectId("59537df80ab10c0001ba8767")
                }
            }
        ]
    },
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5953831367ae0c0001bc87e1"),
    "shipments" : {
        "products" : [
            {
                "orderDetails" : {
                    "id" : ObjectId("5953831367ae0c0001bc87e1")
                }
            }
        ]
    },
}]
```

Now, from this collection, I want to filter out the elements in which, any of the values at `shipments.products.orderDetails.id` path is same as value at `_id` path.

I tried:

```
db.orders.aggregate([{
    "$addFields": {
        "same": {
            "$eq": ["$shipments.products.orderDetails.id", "$_id"]
        }
    }
}])
```

to add a field `same` as a flag to decide whether the values are equal, but the value of `same` comes as `false` for all documents.

**EDIT**
What I want to do is compare the `_id` field the the documents with all `shipments.products.orderDetails.id` values in the array.
If even 1 of the `shipments.products.orderDetails.id`s match the value of the `_id` field, I want that document to be present in the final result.

**PS** I am using MongoDB 3.4, and have to use the aggregation pipeline.

Comment: What is your actual intent? The property you are comparing against is in an "array" so what is supposed to be returned if one of the array members is different? Why do you want this logical value returned? Because if your intention is to "select" or dicard the `true/false` conditions then there is a better way. It does not really help that the only data in the question always matches between both values.

Comment: I want all elements in which the `_id` field exists as any off the array elements

Comment: You just got asked a couple of detailed questions. Commenting back with one line that does not explain any better than your question does is not helping. The lengthy comment is because your question is unclear. Make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current attempt fails because the notation returns an "array" in comparison with a "single value".

So instead either use [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) where available, which can compare to see if one value is "in" an array:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "same": {
      "$in": [ "$_id", "$shipments.products.orderDetails.id" ]  
    }  
  }}
])
```

Or notate both as arrays using [`$setIsSubset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/)

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "same": {
      "$setIsSubset": [ "$shipments.products.orderDetails.id", ["$_id"] ]  
    }  
  }}
])
```

Where in that case it's doing a comparison to see if the "sets" have an "intersection" that makes `_id` the "subset" of the array of values.

Either case will return `true` when "any" of the `id` properties within the array entries at the specified path are a match for the `_id` property of the document.